# Unable to execute Trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, triggers

I have tables like CallLogs and Activities.Here,My requirement is for each insertion in CallLogs i need an entry in Activities.for that i am writing a trigger and procedure
I am calling procedure from my trigger

### Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `activity_insert` (IN text TEXT,IN type varchar(250),IN subtype varchar(250),IN date timestamp, IN url TEXT,IN target_id INT(16))
BEGIN

Insert into Activities(text,type,subtype,timestamp,url,Target_ID)values(in_text,in_type,in_subtype,in_date,in_url,in_target_id);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is executed successfully

### Trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `call_logs_insert` 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `call_logs_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `CallLogs`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       CALL activity_insert('message','Calls',NEW.'type',NEW.'date','null',NEW.'Target_ID');
    END;
$$
```

for some of the columns i am giving static data. and for some of columns i am using new table data
When i am trying to execute this trigger i am getting a following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''type',NEW.'date','null',NEW.'Target_ID'); END; $$' at line 4
```

Can any one plz tell me to execute this trigger what are the changes i need to do

Answer (score 0):

Remove **single quote** from table columns

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `call_logs_insert` 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `call_logs_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `CallLogs`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       CALL activity_insert('message','Calls',NEW.type,NEW.date,'null',NEW.Target_ID);
    END;
$$
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply,i did the changes as you said but,now i am getting like #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) ....I am writing trigger in phpmyadmin.Do i need to activate any priviliges